# remote: Permission to/FSJS2.0.git denied to . fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

remote: Permission to MDAZHARMASOODME/FSJS2.0.git denied to MDAZHARMASOOD.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

im unable to push code in github

Answer (score 1):

To definitely be able to login using https protocol, you should first set your authentication credential to the git Remote URI:
For that you can use `git remote set-url` command and then provide your password while next push.